# Plugin Select2 Is always selecting the first option in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-select2

I have been searching for a couple of hours to try to fix this.
I am using the Select2 jquery plugin to get a dropdown with multiple select.

[image]

The problem is that the first option is always selected.
I have tried to use the tag `multiple="multiple"` but ASP.NET doesn't know what is that, only allow me to make it `multiple="true"` or `multiple="false"`

[image]

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

By default Select2 should not be preselecting any value, so my guess is that you are setting the selected value somewhere, probably in the c# code where you are populating the drop down with values. So try to clear the selected index in the Page_Load method 
`slEmployeeRole.SelectedIndex = -1` or in the js document ready part of the page, try clearing the drop down just to be sure that nothing is selected. And use multiple="true". `$('#slEmployeeRole').val(null).trigger('change');`

Comment: Hi ristedb, I have tried to use `slEmployeeRole.SelectedIndex = -1` and it still not working. I will try  `$('#slEmployeeRole').val(null).trigger('change'); I was able to make it work by refreshing the content of the modal with an update panel.

Comment: With `$('#slEmployeeRole').val(null).trigger('change');` dont work too. The trick is make an update to the update panel of the body and the select option by default is gone.